# Why does a new VHDX remain mounted after rebooting - and how can I restore that behaviour after dismounting it once?

Tags: windows-11, mount, automount, vhdx, windows-11-v23h2

I noticed every time after I created a new VHDX (usually Dev Drive) under Windows 11 (23H2) it stays mounted after rebooting.

That is, until I dismount that VHDX once.

Even re-mounting it afterwards in various ways Windows does no longer keep that drive mounted after a reboot. According to the Interwebz, I'm suddenly supposed to create a task scheduler entry that mounts the drive on logon. Wut? Is that really the solution?

While I can do that, I really wonder if it's possible to simply restore Windows' default behaviour of auto-mounting a VHDX the same way that Windows originally ensures the VHDX remains mounted after a reboot?